# SQL Fiddle: Request Entity Too Large

Tags: sql, sqlfiddle

I'm using SQL Fiddle now. I wanted to create several tables and also insert values to the tables. But I got 'Request Entity Too Large' error. Is there a way to change the command line limit?

Any one knows it please reply me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How much data are you cramming in there?

Comment: Hello. There're 5 tables. Each one has around 8 columns and 10-15 rows. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I'm actually surprised Fiddle won't accept this.  Try scaling down the rows and/or columns until it stops choking.

Comment: I tried reducing to two or three tables and it worked. So Fiddle has this limitation and it cannot save tables also...@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Fiddle also seems prone to break.  On so many occasions the site has gone done while I was trying to add a Fiddle to my SO answer.